# react passing functions between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

saw a lot of different answers about this, nothing worked im missing something.
got a function on my main page, want this function to work on a component inside that page.
heres the code, made it simple for us to read

explnation of what im trying to do:
so in Home we have a h1, in red color. i wanna have 3 buttons in different colors that when you click on of them the h1 colors change. pretty simple to do in one page but react got me confused haha

parent component

```
import Buttons from "./buttons/buttons.component";
 import DATA from "./data";


 class Home extends React.Component{

 constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.changeOutline = this.changeOutline.bind(this);
     this.state = {
        Color: "red"
       }
 }

 changeOutline = (event) => {
    var color = event.target.id;
    this.setState({
        outlineColor: color
    })
 }

 render(){
 return(
 <div>
    <h1 style={{this.state.outlineColor}}>HELLO</h1>
    <Buttons />
 </div
```

the Buttons component.

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
        colors: DATA,
        outlineColor: "red"
    }
}



render(){
    
    return(
        <div>
    {
        this.state.colors.map(({ key, id }) => (
            <div className="button"
                id={id}
                key={key}
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: id 
                }}
             
                onClick={() => this.props.changeOutline}
                >button
                </div>
        ))
    }
    </div>
    )
}
}
```

how Data Looks

```
const DATA = [
{
    key: 1,
    id: "#ff9966"
},
{
    key: 2,
    id: "#66d9ff"
},
{
    key: 3,
    id: "#ff66b3"
}
]
export default DATA;
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot pass props `changeOutline` to `Buttons`:

```
<Buttons changeOutline={this.changeOutline} />
```

And need to call this function on click:

```
onClick={(e) => this.props.changeOutline(e)}
```

Comment: right! now the problem is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined", (the target is from the function im trying to pass, i guess because this "target" isnt on the same component?)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot event. I updated my answer